# ¿cómo extraer los valores de un array?

Tags: javascript, array, parametros

Bien, estoy usando algo tipo libreria `js` de cálculos que encontré,  en este caso quiero hacer algo tipo una multiplicación donde me piden dos `parámetros`  `(factor, valores_n)`

donde lo que haría seria algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

entonces así es como la estoy usando:

```
var multiplicacion = mult(factor , valores1 , ... valores_n)
```

`factor` = el multiplicador

`valores_n` = los números que quiero multiplicar

y los valores que quiero multiplicar están dentro de un `array`,

```
var contenedor = [-5204.60, -3909.27, 2554.95 , 3390.40 ,  2567.15 , 3986.73]
```

entonces este método no permite ingresar los `valores_n` en `array` los valores deben estar por así decirlo "libres".

objetivo algo así:

```
var multiplicacion = mult(factor ,-5204.60, -3909.27, 2554.95 , 3390.40 ,  2567.15 , 3986.73)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes usar [`Function.prototype.apply( )`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Function/apply):

> El método `apply( )` invoca una determinada función asignando explícitamente el objeto `this` y un *array* o similar (*array like object*) como parámetros (argumentos) para dicha función.

Como dicha función solo trabaja con *arrays*, si quires usar algún valor no presente en el *array*, tendrás que añadirlo tu *a mano*:

```
var contenedor = [-5204.60, -3909.27, 2554.95 , 3390.40 ,  2567.15 , 3986.73];

contenedor.unshift( factor );

var multiplicacion = mult.apply( this, contenedor );
```

Si no puedes modificar el contenedor original, tendrás que crear otro.

Comment: perfecto, funciona como esperaba. muchas gracias

Answer (score 5):

Puedes usar el [`operador de propagación`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Spread_operator), con el cual te ahorras de *toquetear* tu *array*:

> El operador de propagación (*spread operator*) permite que una expresión sea expandida en situaciones donde se esperan múltiples argumentos (llamadas a funciones) o múltiples elementos (arrays literales).

```
var contenedor = [-5204.60, -3909.27, 2554.95 , 3390.40 ,  2567.15 , 3986.73];

var multiplicacion = mult( factor, ...contenedor );
```

Comment: muchas gracias por el dato.

Comment: @DAD Esta respuesta es *mas mejor*, entendería si la marcaras como *la usada* :-)

Comment: @Trauma, de hecho si es mas simple, las dos cumplen lo que quiero, pero por decirlo así llegaste "primero". si quieres dar el visto a esta respuesta lo hago, por pedido personal, pero si no sigue igual.